# Webpack 4 chunks size reducing

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, chunks

I'm splitting my build bundle on different chunks, but getting warnings about size limits, tried to find decision by myself, without results.

My current `optimization` config:

```
optimization: {
        moduleIds: 'hashed',
        noEmitOnErrors: true,
        concatenateModules: true,
        occurrenceOrder: true,
        sideEffects: true,
        usedExports: true,
        namedModules: false,
        namedChunks: false,
        splitChunks: {
            maxSize: 480000,
            minSize: 240000,
            chunks: "all"
        },
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin()
        ],
    },
```

How to split my bundle on more chunks with smaller size?
[image]

And other warning is about Entrypoints...
Please give me some advices to fix it.
[image]

Comment: Diagnose which are your biggest dependencies. See if you can include them in different ways (Some packages allow you to import a function, instead of the entire package for one specific function).

Comment: Lodash and momentjs, started to change lodash imports, but it is increased entrypoints size

Comment: lodash, I believe you can use something like import xyz from 'lodash/xyz' and save ample size there.

Comment: Yes, I have changed it like this, but size increased

Comment: You can try using [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer) to see why the chunks are getting so big. Chances are, like others have pointed out, you are importing **entire libraries** instead of required submodules. For example, for lodash, you should use [lodash-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-es) instead, so that you only import the modules you need. This helps webpack during the tree-shaking process, where it sheds modules that are not required in the final build.